# Tengo que ingresar un numero de 4 dígitos y reportar que todos sean pares

Tags: java

```
    int numero;
    System.out.print("Ingrese número: ");
    numero=entrada.nextInt();

     if(numero%2==0)
       System.out.println("ES PAR ");

     else
        System.out.println("ES IMPAR ");
```

Ejemplo:

> al ingresar 7286 no cumple la condición ya que el número 7 no es par

Answer (score 0):

Basta hacer con una simple operaciones aritmetica para recorrer digito por digito y  evaluar si es par o impar

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 7286;
    boolean flag = true;

    while (number > 0) {
        int digit = number % 10;

        if (digit % 2 != 0) flag = false;
        number = number / 10;
    }

    if(flag)
        System.out.println("Todos los digitos son pares ");
    else
        System.out.println("Algun digito es impar");
}
```

Segunda Version,

Supondre que siempre el numero tengra 4 digitos y no querras usar ciclos unicamente variables e if's

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 7286;

    boolean d1 = (number%10)%2==0 ? true : false;
    boolean d2 = ((number/10)%10) %2==0 ? true : false;
    boolean d3 = ((number/100)%10) %2==0 ? true : false;;
    boolean d4 = ((number/1000)%10) %2==0 ? true : false;;

    if(d1 && d2 && d3 && d4){
        System.out.println("todos los digitos son pares");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("algun digito es impar");
    }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero como seria sin while y solo aplicar if.

Answer (score 0):

esta es una versión recuperando el valor en `String` y utilizando `JOptionPane`.

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {

        String numero = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un número");

        for (int i = 0; i < numero.length(); i++) {

            if ((Integer.parseInt("" + numero.charAt(i)) % 2) != 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El dígito (" + numero.charAt(i) + ") es impar");
                break;
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Todos los dígitos son par");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Saludos.